# RestTemplate .get() and .post()

Tags: java, rest, soap

I am converting from SOAP To REST.  I have two different Test calls.  I have figured out the uri and the headers, but what I don't know is .get() and .post().  What do I need to use in REST to accomplish this?

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getGetResponse(URI uri, String wamUsername) {     
    return new Request().uri(uri)
                        .header("Accept", "application/hal+json")
                        .header("Authorization", authHeaders.getAuth())
                        .header("wam-authenticated-username", wamUsername)
                        **.get(String.class)**;
}

public ResponseEntity<?> getPostResponse(URI uri, String wamUsername, Object obj) {
    return new Request().uri(uri)
                        .header("Accept", "application/hal+json")
                        .header("Authorization", authHeaders.getAuth())
                        .header("wam-authenticated-username", wamUsername)
                        **.post(obj)**;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getGetResponse(URI uri, String wamUsername) {   

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Accept", "application/hal+json");
    headers.add("Authorization", authHeaders.getAuth());
    headers.add("wam-authenticated-username", wamUsername);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

    return restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

}

public ResponseEntity<?> getPostResponse(URI uri, String wamUsername, Object obj) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Accept", "application/hal+json");
    headers.add("Authorization", authHeaders.getAuth());
    headers.add("wam-authenticated-username", wamUsername);
    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(obj, headers);

    return restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);

}
```